# Randomise matrix while keeping position of NAs in R

Tags: r, matrix, na

I have a matrix of values that also contains NAs like:

```
> matrix(rexp(200), 10)
> df[ df < 0.5 ] <- NA

> df
         [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]     [,5]
[1,] 2.124043 1.6119230        NA 0.7222127 1.400924
[2,] 4.143728        NA        NA 1.0343577       NA
[3,] 2.395984 0.6794447 0.8327695 1.0258656       NA
[4,]       NA        NA        NA        NA 1.421674
[5,]       NA 1.0446031 0.7762776        NA       NA
```

I would like to scramble each column in my matrix and realised that I can do so using:

```
> df<- df[sample(nrow(df)),] 

> df
         [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]     [,5]
[1,] 2.395984 0.6794447 0.8327695 1.0258656       NA
[2,] 2.124043 1.6119230        NA 0.7222127 1.400924
[3,]       NA        NA        NA        NA 1.421674
[4,] 4.143728        NA        NA 1.0343577       NA
[5,]       NA 1.0446031 0.7762776        NA       NA
```

However, I would like to randomise this way, while keeping the positiong of NAs the same as before.  Does anybody know of an easy way to do so?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap it in an `apply` to randomize the columns only

```
apply(X = df,
      MARGIN = 2,
      FUN = function(x) {
                         x[which(!is.na(x))] <- sample(x[which(!is.na(x))])
                         return(x)
                        })
```

Comment: You can leave out the `which` as `is.na` already returns a logical vector and you don't have any problems with `NA`s in that